# Can you interrupt a soft NFS mount or does it need to timeout?

Tags: nfs, timeout

I know that with hard mounts the only way to interrupt them is to use the `intr` option (which is now deprecated). For soft mounts, however, do you need to wait for the timeout or can you interrupt them?